# Dimension of set of $3\times 3$ matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Calculate the dimension of the image and kernel of each linear transformation. (Hint: you do not need to find a matrix representing the linear transformation.)

$(a)$ $P\colon\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ by (orthogonal) projection onto the plane $x+y-4z=0$

$(b)$ $T\colon M_{3,3}\to\Bbb R$ by $T(M)=$ trace of $M(=$ sum of diagonal elements of $M.)$

$(c)$ $D\colon \mathcal P_3\to\mathcal P_3$ by $D(p(x))=P'(x)$ where $\mathcal P_3$ is the vector space of polynomials in $x$ of degree $\le 3.$

*Answer.*

$(a)$ dimension of image $= 2$; dimension of kernel $=1$

$(b)$ dimension of image $= 1$; dimension of kernel $=3$

$(c)$ dimension of image $= 3$; dimension of kernel $=1$

In part $(b)$, why is the dimension of image $=1$? Alternatively, why is the dimension of $M_{3,3}=4$?

Thanks

Comment: Is $M_{3,3}$ the vector space of $3\times 3$-matrices? That doesn't sound right... it should be (b) dimension image = 1 dimension kernel = 8...

Comment: Dimension for $M_{3, 3}= 9$

Comment: @Jake Probably just an error in the key, maybe they read it as $M_{2,2}$.

Comment: I think for part b kernel is equal to 2

Comment: "why is the dimension of image=1?" Because it's a map into $\Bbb R$, so the dimension is less than $2$, and it's not the zero map, so the dimension is higher than $0$.

Comment: Dimension of the kernel for part (b) is 8, not 3. Consider the 6 standard basis matrices with 0's on the diagonal, these are certainly in the kernel. Then there are two other matrices with entries on the diagonal that are in the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

$\dim\mathcal M_{3,3}=9$, and $\operatorname{Tr}$ is clearly surjective (any number is the trace of a matrix), hence by the *rank-nullity theorem*,
$$\dim(\ker(\operatorname{Tr}))=8.$$